# How do you know when you can perform an ultimate jutsu in Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution?

Tags: naruto-uns-revolution

I've been trying out Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution recently, and it doesn't seem to make any sense when you can and can't use your ultimate or team ultimate jutsu.

When playing as the ultimate jutsu type, there's a reddish-orange bar to the side of your health that seems like it would indicate this. However, I have on occasion been able to use ultimate jutsu when it's not full, and I have also on occasion not been able to use it when it is full. So that bar seemingly has no bearing on ultimate jutsu, unless I'm not understanding it.

There's also some cases where there's a popup showing the button combination to press to use the ultimate jutsu, but I've been able to use it without that popup being present.

What are the exact circumstances under which you an use ultimate jutsu? How can I tell mid-battle?

Answer (score 1):

The blue bar beneath your health is your chakra bar. This is used for jutsu attacks, ultimate jutsu, and chakra dash/backdash. The red bar is your Team bar, which powers up as you use your assists. On your chakra bar should be a small, circular mark that indicates the minimum amount of chakra required for an ultimate jutsu attack. When your red Team gauge is filled, you can triple-tap the chakra load button for a team ultimate jutsu, which is far more damaging and much harder to dodge. This does not require more chakra than a normal ultimate jutsu.

Also note that in Revolution you must use the Ultimate Jutsu battle style to use ultimate jutsu, and certain character/assist character combinations have combination ultimate jutsu. For instance, using Sasori and Deidara grants an enhanced ultimate jutsu attack. This only works if you have only the characters for a combination ultimate in your team; having Sasori, Deidara, and Kabuto will cause you to use the base ultimate jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I believe I have this figured out.

You can use your Ultimate Jutsu any time you have enough chakra, regardless of the state of the reddish-orange bar near your health. The requisite amount of chakra is indicated by a red mark on the bar.

Having a full Ultimate Jutsu bar simply allows you to do a powered up version of your Ultimate Jutsu, which also requires that you have a *full* chakra bar. This is accomplished by pressing the chakra button *thrice* instead of the normal twice to activate the ultimate jutsu.